# Wordpress messed up our htaccess redirect, how to modify to work with Wordpress' htaccess code?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We had several domains parked on top of our main website. This was a normal HTML website and we used the following redirect so that the domain would 301 redirect to the proper url to avoid getting dinged by Google.

```
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourmainsiteurl\.com$ 
rewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.ourmainsiteurl.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

So the above htaccess code just rewrites the url to www.ourmainsiteurl.com, which is what we want.

Now here's the problem... we installed Wordpress and it has the following default htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tried to add my redirect code in but that broke Wordpress. Can anyone tell me what I need to use to make this work?

**Simply put I want all the parked domains (ie: parkedurl1.com, parkedurl2.com, etc) to be redirected to www.ourmainsiteurl.com with the htaccess file.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the redirect is **before** any wordpress rules:

```
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ourmainsiteurl\.com$ [NC]
rewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.ourmainsiteurl.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If it's still not working, check to see if wordpress has something turned on that is redirecting, or adding/removing the "www" from the hostname.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I even tried putting the redirect after the RewriteBase rule and then it just errors out and the page doesn't load.